# Is there a documented convention for the longitude of the North and South poles?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am working on plus codes, which is a formal specification for encoding areas bounded by north, south, east and west latitudes and longitudes.

We need to decide if the North and South poles shall be specified as belonging to one or infinitely many possible encodings.

The mathematician may say "they're just numbers, encode (+90, X) however you want". But the application designer might say "every place should encode to one coordinate and every coordinate to one place".

Is there any geographic information system specification which assigns the North and South 90th "parallel" to a specific longitude?

Comment: It is interesting. I looked online for a standard definition. Wikipedia says longitude is arbitrary. https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-times-zones-are-prevalent-at-the-geographic-north-pole-and-south-pole.html says that time zones are arbitrary as well. The UTM entry in Wikipedia, for example, says "The polar regions south of 80°S and north of 84°N are excluded.", so the issue doesn't arise. Maybe you will need to say it's 0° Longitude as a standard. I'm not sure anyone could reasonably argue with you. The product of latitude and longitude at the pole would be zero if that helps.